# How to send Firebase Auth ID Token from client SDK to Node/Express Middleware in order verify it with Admin SDK?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am getting idToken from Client SDK after successful login from firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken method. I do not want to send this token to one specific request via AJAX, instead, I want to send it to the middleware so that I can check it all of the requests to see if the user is allowed. does it make sense?

Server JS

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

// firebase
var admin = require('firebase-admin');
var serviceAccount = require('../delbay-restaurant-firebase-adminsdk-bqkir-481ca82589.json');


// Initialize only once in the app cycle
admin.initializeApp({
 credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
 databaseURL: "https://delbay-restaurant.firebaseio.com"
});


function isAuthenticated(req, res, next) {

}

router.get('/', isAuthenticated, function(req, res, next) {
    res.render("user"); 
});


module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?